# how can i extract node title and node content for ajax manipulation before node submit?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to perform some operations by ajax before a node is submitted. So, how can I capture the node content and title which has been filled in by the user and pass it onto my ajax callback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here is the code-

So for this you need to specify "hello" as your callback function for the element for which the ajax attribute is being set. 
For example if you want to call this by a button press-

```
$form['test'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t("Testing"),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'hello_ajax',
            'wrapper' => 'newtable_div',
            'effect' => 'slide',
            ),
    );
```

then your callback function should be-

```
function hello_ajax($form, $form_state) {
  $output = '';
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $title = $values['title'];
  $body = '';
  foreach ($values['body'][$values['language']] as $info) {
    $body .= $info['value'];
  }

  $content = check_plain($title) . ' ' . $body;
```

}

$content variable now holds the node title as well as node content, which you can use for further manipulations. cheers !! :)

Comment: what is this wrapper attribute is it necessary to specify this ? Please don't mind if my question sounds a bit vague but I'm new to drupal.

Comment: wrapper specifies the enclosing div tag for the content which will be returned by the ajax callback function. So, in this case, you need to specify a div with #prefix as <div id="newtable_div"> and #suffix as </div>